# Can I access private field of widget, text objects?

Tags: java, reflection

I've already read lots of posts about reflection, and all the examples are just simple access objects of string, double and int, etc.
But, I want to access object like Widget, Text and even self-defining objects.
I've try the same way as string, but it fails.

e.g.

```
class testPrivate{
    public boolean test()
    {
        return true;
    }

}

class button {
public button(){
    anc=new testPrivate();
}
    private testPrivate anc;

}


public class Testing {

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Throwable{
    button bt=new button();
    Field field = bt.getClass().getDeclaredField("anc");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println(field.test());
    }

}
```

**Here, field.test() in the statement System.out.println(field.test()); fails.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Field` is a class that refers to a field on a *class* type, and not any specific instance of that class.

In order to invoke a method, you first need an instance of that class, and then you have to make sure that anc is not null.

Example:

```
button bt=new button();
Field field = bt.getClass().getDeclaredField("anc");
field.setAccessible(true);

//This sets the field value for the instance "bt"
field.set(bt, new testPrivate());
```

Then in order to invoke the method, you need to get that object and invoke the method on that object:

```
//Since field corresponds to "anc" it will get the value
//of that field on whatever object you pass (bt in this example).
testPrivate tp = (testPrivate) field.get(bt);
System.out.println(tp.test());
```

Also on a stylistic note, classes should start with a capital letter, e.g. `button`→`Button` and `testPrivate`→`TestPrivate`